# Image is not updating in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Please help me. I am trying to update the profile in which username and email are updated but the image dose not. My code is....

**profile.html**

```
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Info</legend>
            {{ u_form|crispy }}
            {{ p_form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Account Successfully Updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form' : u_form,
        'p_form' : p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

Comment: Could we see the view as well as the form? Please post the code as an edit to your original post, not a comment

Comment: Thanks for reply I have updated the views.py

Comment: So you're issue here is that when you don't change the image and submit the form, the image is set to nothing. Is that correct?

Comment: No, the issue is when i update the profile then username and email is updated but image is not updating..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue lies in views.py.

Firstly, you are checking to see if the method for retrieving the view is POST. If it is not, you are initializing a form with the POST data that is not present. I have simplified that for you below.

Secondly, you are not passing the POST information to the second form, only the files portion. Have you tried changing the p_form to take both parameters like below?

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Account Successfully Updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form' : u_form,
        'p_form' : p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

Comment: I have reviewed my code again and after updating it with your code it finally works. Thanks for the help.